# How to highlight a button in Android with java code?

Tags: java, android

I've searched around and found the following code, but it's not doing what I want :

```
  private class ButtonListener implements View.OnClickListener
  {
    public void onClick(View v)
    {
      for (int index = 0; index < GATE.col_count + 1; index++)
        if (gateView.isPinButton((Button) v, index))
        {
          gate.Current_Id = index;
//          ((Button) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.rgb(198,68,18));
          ShapeDrawable shapedrawable = new ShapeDrawable();
          shapedrawable.setShape(new RectShape());
          shapedrawable.getPaint().setColor(Color.rgb(88,236,236));
          shapedrawable.getPaint().setStrokeWidth(10f);
          shapedrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.STROKE);
//          shapedrawable.getPaint().setStyle(Paint.Style.FILL_AND_STROKE);
//          ((Button) v).setBackgroundColor(Color.parseColor("#66FF0000"));
          ((Button) v).setBackground(shapedrawable);
          ((Button) v).getBackground().setColorFilter(0x37000000, PorterDuff.Mode.SRC_ATOP);
          v.invalidate();
          return;
        }
    }
  }
```

Before a click the button looks like this :

[image]

After the click it looks like this :

[image]

But what I want is to look like this, so the center of the button is still grey like before, yet the border is highlited :

[image]

So what's the right way to do it from the java code ?

Comment: The purpose of `for` loop in click event?

Comment: The purpose is to find the index of which button so it can set the value for gate.Current_Id

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the answer, it's like this :

```
      GradientDrawable drawable = new GradientDrawable();
      drawable.setShape(GradientDrawable.RECTANGLE);
      drawable.setStroke(5, Color.rgb(66,218,236));
      drawable.setColor(Color.rgb(214,215,215));
      ((Button) v).setBackground(drawable);
```

Answer (score 0):

It isn't the best solution but as option you can place your button in some container for example in the FrameLayout, set the container's width and height as wrap_content, set the background color as transparent or @null and also center the button on it, next you need to set some padding for the container in order to the container became visible behind the button and finally when you click the button just change the background color of the container in your button's onClickListener